# Is there a way to exclude a specific string from a list in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now, I'm trying to build a mock dashboard, but a column has a list attributed to it. Take for example

list `['a','b','c','d']` as part of column 'letters'

Now say, if I want to exclude any rows with 'c' in it, how would I go about creating a query to exclude the letter c from my query? I presume that using LIKE would work, but when I try to use NOT LIKE xxx, it still populates the list containing 'c'

```
SELECT
    *
FROM XXX
WHERE
    status = 'open'
    tag = 'alphabet'
    AND NOT type = 'bugs'
    AND list_item NOT LIKE 'c'
LIMIT
    100
```

Comment: Try **NOT LIKE '%c%'**

Comment: Do not store lists as delimited strings.  If you have to put it in a column in a table, use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If list_item is a string you should put the NOT LIKE '%c%'.

The % symbol indicates whatever character.

If list_item is a list (as the name suggests) you should use

```
list_item NOT IN ['%c%']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add wildcards (%) around the letter, as its written it will only exclude values that are literally 'c'.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM XXX
WHERE
    status = 'open'
    tag = 'alphabet'
    AND NOT type = 'bugs'
    AND list_item NOT LIKE '%c%'
LIMIT
    100
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `NOT LIKE` with `NOT REGEXP` and you're good to go. With `REGEXP`, you don't need the `%`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM XXX
WHERE
    status = 'open'
    tag = 'alphabet'
    AND NOT type = 'bugs'
    AND list_item NOT REGEXP 'c'
LIMIT
    100
```